# Trying to Remove Errors from this SQL Query

Tags: sql, date, time, casting

I have a fairly long SQL Query that converts a numeric date data type to a date time value and further specifies the search based on my requirements.  However I am receiving a couple of errors that I cannot seem to get around and I was wondering if anyone can make a modification to my query for it to run error free.

This is my query:

```
SELECT [Object] AS [Dataset],
CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
  LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
 MsgId,
 Parms,
CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6)
    ELSE '' --Optional ELSE
END  AS [Dataset],
FROM ( SELECT  ItemId,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
[Object],
MsgID,
Parms,
FROM JnlDataSection
WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove       the time part
WHERE SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) = 'X05219'
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC;
```

### These are the errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 22

Please Note: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
```

Answer (score 2):

you have an extra comma just before the FROM:

```
END  AS [Dataset],
```

should just be

```
END  AS [Dataset]
```

Comment: without knowing the record you're trying to retrieve, i'll take a guess and say that the substring in one of the where clauses is probably wrong.  Start by trying to query for just that substrings and see if you can pull that record.

Comment: it looks like your extraction from [DATE] into DATE and TIME is incorrect.  You are putting the same string into 'Date' and 'Time'

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the comma after [Dataset] on the lilne above it. Also

```
Parms,
FROM JnlDataSection
```

there shouldn't be a comma after Parms

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "," before the from clauses. The new query should look like the following...

```
SELECT [Object] AS [Dataset],
  CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
  SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
  SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS DATE) 'Date',
  LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,CONVERT(DATETIME,LEFT([Date],8)+' '+
 SUBSTRING([Date],10,2)+':'+
 SUBSTRING([Date],12,2)+':'+
 SUBSTRING([Date],14,2)+'.'+
 SUBSTRING([Date],15,3))) AS TIME),8) 'Time',
 MsgId,
 Parms,
 CASE WHEN MsgID = '61' THEN SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6)
 ELSE '' --Optional ELSE
 END  AS [Dataset]
FROM ( SELECT  ItemId,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(18),[Date]) [Date],
[Object],
MsgID,
Parms
FROM JnlDataSection
WHERE CAST(substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 0, 5) + '-' +
substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 5, 2) + '-' +
substring(convert(varchar(50), [Date]), 7, 2) AS DATETIME) =
CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()))) A --Converting to date again to remove          the time part
WHERE SUBSTRING(Parms,35,6) = 'X05219'
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC;
```

Comment: It is running error free but the columns are empty for some reason.

Comment: This could be for a number of reasons. The best thing to do is to break the query down into smaller pieces. I would first run your subquery with no where clause. If records come back, start adding the where clauses one by one until you find which one is preventing records from returning.